# CNN model input, output size error (image training)

Tags: pytorch, model, conv-neural-network, runtime-error

```
class FashionClassifier(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, num_classes):
    super(FashionClassifier, self).__init__()
    self.conv_layers = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
    )


    self.conv_output_size = self._get_conv_output_size()

    self.fc_layers = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(in_features=self.conv_output_size, out_features=3),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Dropout(0.5),  # Add dropout for regularization
        nn.Linear(in_features=3, out_features=num_classes)
    )

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.conv_layers(x)
    x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
    x = self.fc_layers(x)
    return x

def _get_conv_output_size(self):
    test_input = torch.randn(1, 32, 224, 224)
    with torch.no_grad():
        test_output = self.conv_layers(test_input)
        return test_output.view(test_output.size(0), -1).size(1)
```

---

When i train an image in size 224 * 224 * 32 using a CNN model
The following error will occur.

> > > RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 3, 3], expected input[1, 32, 224, 224] to have 3 channels, but got 32 channels instead

### Following the error message, I changed the input size of [1, 3, 224, 224] as shown below (32 > 3)

---

```
    def _get_conv_output_size(self):
    test_input = torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224)
    with torch.no_grad():
        test_output = self.conv_layers(test_input)
        return test_output.view(test_output.size(0), -1).size(1)
```

---

The following error will occur this time.

> > > TypeError: conv2d() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (dict, Parameter, Parameter, tuple, tuple, tuple, int), but expected one of:

- (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, tuple of ints padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
  didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (!dict!, !Parameter!, !Parameter!, !tuple of (int, int)!, !tuple of (int, int)!, !tuple of (int, int)!, int)
- (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, str padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
  didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (!dict!, !Parameter!, !Parameter!, !tuple of (int, int)!, !tuple of (int, int)!, !tuple of (int, int)!, int)

---

What is the problem? I would appreciate your feedback.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch image are expected to be of shape `B x C x H x W`, for batch, channel, height, width.

Your dummy input in the `_get_conv_output_size` function is of shape `1 x 32 x 224 x 224`. However, if you look at the first layer of your network, you'll see that your creating it with input channels of 3:

```py
    self.conv_layers = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, padding=1), # here
        nn.ReLU(),
```

According to the [Conv2d documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html):

> `in_channels` (int) – Number of channels in the input image

So you want to do instead

```py
    self.conv_layers = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, padding=1), # here
        nn.ReLU(),
```

Comment: but when i fixed code like "in_channels = 32", i received the following error message."TypeError: conv2d() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (dict, Parameter, Parameter, tuple, tuple, tuple, int), but expected one of:
 * (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, tuple of ints padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (!dict!, !Parameter!, !Parameter!, !tuple of (int, int)!, !tuple of (int, int)!, !tuple of (int, int)!, int)

Comment: @choipI I copied your code, replaced 3 by 32 in the `in_channels` of the first conv2d of the `conv_layers` and it worked for me without issue. I suspect from your error message that you are doing more than that, as you have dict. You should look at the error message and check what you did

Comment: "num_classes = 3
  net = FashionClassifier(num_classes).to(DEVICE)"  This is code that initializes FashionClassfier class. I can't find the cause of the error message being printed. what is the problem? :(

Comment: @choipi Again I'm sorry, strictly copying the first code in your question, replacing the 3 by 32 and doing what you do works for me. If you have more issue, ask another questions. I have no idea what you are doing wrong since I can't see it